# I deleted my dict, but my dict_keys don't mind, why is that?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

Since `dict.keys` (and `dict.items` and `dict.values` alike) returns a view of the dictionary object, I would assume that deleting the dictionary they were produced from to actually have an effect on the `dict_keys` we got them from.

With a simple dictionary and it's keys:

```
d = {i:i for i in range(20)}
k = d.keys()  # similarly with d.values and d.items
```

Apparently, this isn't the case:

```
del d
i = iter(k)
list(i) # works fine and prints the keys
```

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Answer (score 9):

`del d` deletes the *variable* `d`, but the *object* that it refers to will continue to exist if there are other references.  You don't need a dictionary view to observe this:

```
>>> d = {i:i for i in range(5)}
>>> dd = d
>>> d['x'] = 'x'
>>> del d
>>> d
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'd' is not defined
>>> dd
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 'x': 'x'}
```

(The `d['x']='x'` line demonstrates that `dd=d` does *not* copy the dictionary itself, it only makes an additional reference.)

Also contrast the behavior of `clear`, which modifies the actual object:

```
>>> d = {i:i for i in range(5)}
>>> k = d.keys()
>>> del d
>>> list(k)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> d = {i:i for i in range(5)}
>>> k = d.keys()
>>> d.clear()
>>> list(k)
[]
```

Answer (score 4):

Calling `d.keys()` on the object simply increases the reference count for the dictionary object; `del d` won't trigger the garbage collector for the object labeled by the name `d` since the reference will always be larger than zero.

You can see the reference count for the dictionary object increase when `d.keys()` is called by using `sys.getrefcount`:

```
from sys import getrefcount
d = {i:i for i in range(20)}
getrefcount(d) # 2
k = d.keys() 
getrefcount(d) # 3 (+1 due to d.keys())
```

in the call that constructs the dictionary view this [reference increment can be seen](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a458911bf0a2578adcbe1428a1227d0e202c2622/Objects/dictobject.c#L3801):

```
Py_INCREF(dict);
dv->dv_dict = (PyDictObject *)dict;
```

It's done just before the object is stored in the corresponding entry of the view object struct.

Since a view is really just an iterable object with a reference to the underlying dict, you can also go one step deeper and delete the keys object after getting its iterator and still have the ability to get the values:

```
i = iter(k) # +1 reference
del k, d
next(i)     # 0
```

[`iter(k)` increases the reference count](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a458911bf0a2578adcbe1428a1227d0e202c2622/Objects/dictobject.c#L3388) for the original dictionary by one *again*, keeping the object away from collection.

Comment: Yes @AlexFung, this is allowed when you're able to do it properly (which I try my best to do). See here [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard cool. I was not aware that immediate self answer is encouraged